# Javascript DOM styling

Tags: javascript, dom, styles, parent-node

I want to reach the parentnode of my list (with an id selector)and style it adding a background color using plain javascript. This is my code, but doesn't work.

```
    var listParentNode;
    listParentNode = getElementById("list2").parentNode;
    listParentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#deff00";
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work and how I can fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementById is a function of document.

```
var listParentNode = document.getElementById("list2").parentNode;
```

Comment: Forgot to type document. But my code still doesn't work.

Comment: No. The weird thing is that it works when I type it in the console, but not when i refresh the page.

Comment: Does @Bill Dong solution work? what's your html structured. You should include it in your question.

Comment: Restarted Chrome and got it to work! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes restart chrome will help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var listParentNode;
listParentNode = document.getElementById("list2").parentNode;
listParentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#deff00";
```

```html
<div>parent div
  <div id="list2">inside div</div>
</div>
```

you should use document.getElementById

Comment: Forgot to type document. But my code still doesn't work.